# Local-freeness of the Hodge bundle

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ is a proper flat morphism of locally noetherian schemes, with all of its fibers being geometrically integral regular curves of genus $g$ (so $h^{0}(X|_{q},\mathscr{O}_{X|_{q}})=1$ for all $q\in Y$). In particular $f$ is smooth of relative dimension $1$, and $\mathscr{O}_{Y} = f_{\ast}\mathscr{O}_{X}$. I would like to verify that the pushforward $f_{\ast}\Omega_{X/Y}$, the so called Hodge bundle, is a locally free sheaf (of rank $g$). Cf. R.Vakil's note, exercise 28.1.N.

Using cohomology and base change theorem ("for $p=2$"), one can reduce to the fact that $R^{1}f_{\ast}\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free. In fact as $H^{2}(X_{q},\Omega_{X_{q}/q})=0$ by dimensional vanishing, $R^{2}f_{\ast}\Omega_{X/Y}=0$ is forced (it is hence locally free), and hence by cohomology and base change theorem, $R^{1}f_{\ast}\Omega_{X/Y}|_{q}\to H^{1}(X_{q},\Omega_{X_{q}/q})$ is surjective (in fact bijective) for all $q$. To proceed further, I think one must prove $R^{1}f_{\ast}\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free (at least to use the base change theorem for "$p=1$"). (As $h^{1}(X_{q},\Omega) = h^{0}(X_{q},\mathscr{O})=1$ we know $R^{1}f_{\ast}\Omega_{X/Y}$ must be a line bundle.) But I don't have any idea on proving this fact by hand yet. Are there any ways of tackling this (perhaps, without quoting too much, like Grothendieck-Serre duality)?

Comment: I don't think you can really get away from using duality here. This is written up nicely (at least in the case of elliptic schemes) in 'Geometric modular forms' by Hida, chapter 2. I would look there.

Comment: @Alex Youcis Thanks so much! I just have checked the G-S duality part of Hida's book you mentioned and I found everything I wanted.

Comment: @Alex Youcis I just have added the answer below. Again thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex Youcis have mentioned in the comment above, H.Hida's [Geometric Modular Forms and Elliptic Curves] contains a proof of the fact that $R^{1}f_{\ast}\Omega_{X/Y}\approx \mathscr{O}_{Y}$ in 2.1.2 Grothendieck-Serre duality, pp. 96-97. The rest of the proof is straightforward---the local freeness implies $R^{0}f_{\ast}\Omega_{X/Y}|_{q}\to H^{0}(X_{q},\Omega_{X_{q}})$ are isomorphisms, and as "$p=-1$ case" fiber maps are trivially surjective, we know $f_{\ast}\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank $g$.